# SQL: Pivoting rows to columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to pivot survey response data based on response ID and time.

For example, my orginal table SURVEY_RESPONSES looks like this, with an rating scale and score associated with the same response time for each response:

| customer_ID | response_time | value | disp_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/23 09:10 | Likert Scale | Rating Scale |
| 1 | 1/1/23 09:10 | 5 | Score |
| 1 | 1/2/23 08:30 | 0-10 | Rating Scale |
| 1 | 1/2/23 08:30 | 7 | Score |
| 2 | 1/4/23 11:00 | Satisfaction | Rating Scale |
| 2 | 1/4/23 11:00 | Moderate | Score |

I am trying to pivot so that my output looks like this, with a column for scale and score matched to the corresponding response ID and time:

| customer_ID | response_time | Scale | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/23 09:10 | Likert Scale | 5 |
| 1 | 1/2/23 08:30 | 0-10 | 7 |
| 2 | 1/4/23 11:00 | Satisfaction | Moderate |

I have tried case when statements, but am getting mismatches with IDs and response times.
Using Snowflake.

Thank you

Comment: that is a simple unpivot there must be hundreds of samplr here. have you tried one?

Comment: Yes. I have tried case when statements I found from searching here, but since I am not familiar with pivot syntax I am struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A manual pivot is trivial for this data.

```
with data(customer_ID, response_time, value, disp_name) as (
    select $1, to_timestamp($2, 'mm/dd/yy hh:mi'), $3, $4
    from values
        (1, '1/1/23 09:10', 'Likert Scale', 'Rating Scale'),
        (1, '1/1/23 09:10', '5', 'Score'),
        (1, '1/2/23 08:30', '0-10', 'Rating Scale'),
        (1, '1/2/23 08:30', '7', 'Score'),
        (2, '1/4/23 11:00', 'Satisfaction', 'Rating Scale'),
        (2, '1/4/23 11:00', 'Moderate', 'Score')
)
select 
    customer_ID, 
    response_time,
    max(iff(disp_name = 'Rating Scale', value, null)) as scale,
    max(iff(disp_name = 'Score', value, null)) as score
from data
group by 1,2
order by 1,2;
```

gives:

| CUSTOMER_ID | RESPONSE_TIME | SCALE | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 09:10:00.000 | Likert Scale | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 08:30:00.000 | 0-10 | 7 |
| 2 | 2023-01-04 11:00:00.000 | Satisfaction | Moderate |

and the PIVOT SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM data
    PIVOT(max(value) FOR disp_name IN ('Rating Scale', 'Score'))
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

[image]

Comment: amazingly simple, thank you!